# Difference between Scala Option's isDefined and nonEmpty method

Tags: scala

In Scala Option, what is the difference between its isDefined and nonEmpty method? Is there any performance difference between the two?

Comment: the source is often a useful resource

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Looking at the source, the definition of `nonEmpty` is:

> final def nonEmpty = isDefined

Comment: Not really, it is the other way around. `def isDefined: Boolean = !isEmpty` from https://www.assembla.com/code/scala-eclipse-toolchain/git/nodes/src/library/scala/Option.scala?rev=53a319a9d27fe1cff7ad9346f4d4f16203ddae80

Comment: No, Lee definitely had it right, your link is to some weird and/or old fork. https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L194

Comment: @Kigyo - Well that's the definition of `isDefined` but the question is about the relationship between `nonEmpty` and `isDefined`.

Comment: @Lee: The relationship would be described logically as "equivalence." What is sometimes written in mathematical papers as `iff` (if and only if). In other words, they're the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

From [Scala 2.13.x](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Option.scala) codebase, it's:

```
def isDefined: Boolean = !isEmpty
...
final def nonEmpty = isDefined
```

So, logically, no difference between the two.

Answer (score 4):

They are literally the same. I believe `nonEmpty` is provided mostly for consistency with the Collection API.

Answer (score 3):

You might look at it the other way around.

If `Option` didn't provide `nonEmpty`, it would be provided through the conversion to an `Iterable`, which invokes `toList`.

Do you want to turn your `Option` into a `List` just to check that property?  Of course not.

So the issue is not whether `nonEmpty` is more efficient vis-a-vis `isDefined`, but vis-a-vis the conversion.

If it relied on the conversion, it would wind up doing `lengthCompare`, which creates an iterator as overhead.

So the answer is that you may use whichever method you prefer.